# Python Keyboard and Pynput Mouse modules multi-threading conflict

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard, python-multithreading, pynput

I get an error about 50% of the time that I run my program with multithreading. Each component works individually, and each thread runs without error except for the Mouse listener and the thread that reads keyboard events. I assume this has to do with the read_event() function from the keyboard module creating a thread itself, but I'm not certain on how to work around this. When I remove the read_event() line, multi-threading works. I can also run he mouse listener with the other threads in the program without error (and same with the keyboard thread). I was previously using multiprocessing without error, but I thought multithreading would minimize the cpu usage as each 4 components are taking a lot of input/output. I am trying to avoid going back to multiprocessing. The actual program is about 5 files with many lines of code, but I've minimized the issue to the following blocks of code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p2 = Thread(target = f, args=(participant_id_action,), daemon=True) #, args=(cap,'database',cap,"VGG-Face"))
    p2.start()

    p1 = Thread(target=DeepFace.stream, args=('database',"DeepFace",),daemon=True)
    p1.start()

    p4 = Thread(target=h, args=(participant_id_context,), daemon=True)
    p4.start()

    listener=mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click,on_scroll=on_scroll,on_move=on_move)
    listener.start()

    file = open(participant_id_action_mouse, "w")
    flag.f = file

    listener.join()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p4.join()
```

from the main file where multithreading occurs, and:

```
while True:
        event = keyboard.read_event()

        # when user session is done
        if flag.stop:
            return
```

from the keylogging file.

The traceback that occurs is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 431, in listen
    KeyEventListener(callback).run()
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 366, in run
    loopsource = Quartz.CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(None, self.tap, 0)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 168, in __getattr__
    value = getattr(p, name)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 168, in __getattr__
    value = getattr(p, name)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    value = self.__get_constant(name)
  File "/Users/londonbielicke/Documents/Code/dreu/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 414, in __get_constant
    self.__funcmap.pop(name)
KeyError: 'CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource'
```

Comment: Also wanted to add that this is running on macOS. Haven't heard from anybody testing on Windows that they are seeing this error yet.

Comment: From the traceback it looks like something is not getting initialized properly.  The error occurs inside a library during some kind of lazy initialization process.  With multithreading your program's execution sequence is non-deterministic, unless you explicitly add synchronization steps to your code.

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue by adding a time.sleep() between starting threads. Thanks!